# Objects and classes in Rust

Tags: oop, rust

I am fiddling around with Rust, going by the examples, trying to make a class.  I have been looking at the [example of `StatusLineText`](https://github.com/pcwalton/sprocketnes/blob/bd3795b9e7931da4abeb7c697bd5d14a64584308/gfx.rs#L249)

It keeps raising the errors:

```
error: `self` is not available in a static method. Maybe a `self` argument is missing? [E0424]
            self.id + self.extra
            ^~~~

error: no method named `get_total` found for type `main::Thing` in the current scope
    println!("the thing's total is {}", my_thing.get_total());
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~
```

My code is rather simple:

```
fn main() {
    struct Thing {
        id: i8,
        extra: i8,
    }

    impl Thing {
        pub fn new() -> Thing {
            Thing { id: 3, extra: 2 }
        }
        pub fn get_total() -> i8 {
            self.id + self.extra
        }
    }

    let my_thing = Thing::new();
    println!("the thing's total is {}", my_thing.get_total());
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to add an explicit `self` parameter to make [methods](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/method-syntax.html):

```
fn get_total(&self) -> i8 {
    self.id + self.extra
}
```

Functions without the explicit `self` parameter are considered [associated functions](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/method-syntax.html#associated-functions), which can be called without a specific instance.

Comment: To clarify, self must now be explicitly declared in the parameters of methods, as of Rust 0.6